# F# matching expression and 'as' pattern

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

I'm studying some F# and trying to implement a parser combinator like in [this tutorial](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/understanding-parser-combinators/); after some copy and paste of the proposed solution, I tried to customize it by myself.

Surely there's something I missed but the compiler gives me a weird error message.

```ml
type T<'a> =
    | A of string
    | B of 'a

let foo a b =
    match a with
    | A s as x -> x
    | B i ->
        match b with
        | A s as x -> x
        | B j ->
            B (i, j)
```

The code above is a generalization of the issue I found: the error is notified in the last result (the B branch of the innermost matching expression):

```
error FS0001: Type mismatch. Expecting a
    'a
but given a
    'a * 'b
The resulting type would be infinite when unifying ''a' and ''a * 'b'
```

But if I don't use the `as` pattern:

```ml
let foo a b =
    match a with
    | A s -> A s // it can also be '| A s as x -> A s'
    | B i ->
        match b with
        | A s -> A s
        | B j ->
            B (i, j)
```

then the compiler is happy again.

I don't get why I have to recreate the same *logical* result if it is already there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In

```
A s as x -> x
```

`x` has type `T<'a>` while the required return type for `foo` is `T<('a * 'a)>`. Even though the `A` case does not contain any values of `'a` it does not have a polymorphic type like `forall 'a . T<'a>`. In your second example you are creating a new instance of `A` which can have the required type.

Comment: Ok, now I understand my mistake: I forgot that `A` is a constructor for the type `T` not the type itself, and therefor `x` is not of type `T<'a * 'b>`. Thanks!